# Passing string from onclick to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line:

```
$twizz.html(
  '<a class="username" href="#">' + twizz.user + '</a>' + ': ' + twizz.message
)
```

and a JQuery line that executes a function when clicked:

```
$('.username').click(function() {displayUserTwizz(); return false; });
```

For example. JohnDoe (twizz.user) - Hello everyone (twizz.message) (with John Doe calling the displayUserTwizz function when clicked)

How do I dynamic pass the twizz.user string into my displayUserTwizz function. For example if I click JohnDoe, the function will run as

```
displayUserTwizz = function () {

var index = message.JohnDoe.length;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the content of the `<a>` element (`event.target.innerText`), then pass it to the `displayUserTwizz()` function:

```
$('.username').click(function() {displayUserTwizz(event.target.innerText); return false; });
```

Then, you can handle the user in the `displayUserTwizz()` function:

```
displayUserTwizz = function (user) {

var index = message[user].length;

}
```

Comment: Apologies as I'm just starting out learning this. How do I do this portion? "You need to get the content of the <a> element (event.target.innerText)"

Comment: An event is passed to the function when a click occurs. `event.target` can be used to get the element that caused the event (in this case, it would be `.username`). `event.taget.innerText` then gets the value of the element. For further reference, please read about the [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event).